# Show what the calculated bins breaks are in a histogram

Tags: r, histogram

It is my understanding that when plotting histogram, it's not that every unique data point gets its own bin, there's an algorithm that calculates how many bins to use. How do I find out how the data were partitioned to create the number of bins? E.g. 0-5,6-10,... How do I get R to show me where the breaks are via text output?

I've found various methods to calculate number of bins but that's just theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `$breaks`:

```
  set.seed(10)
  hist(rnorm(200,0,1),20)$breaks
  [1] -2.4 -2.2 -2.0 -1.8 -1.6 -1.4 -1.2 -1.0 -0.8 -0.6 -0.4 -0.2  0.0  0.2  0.4  0.6  0.8  1.0  1.2  1.4  1.6  1.8  2.0  2.2  2.4
```

Comment: Additionally, you can change the "break" behaviour using the `breaks` argument in the `hist` function as per the manual pages "The default for breaks is "Sturges": see nclass.Sturges. Other names for which algorithms are supplied are "Scott" and "FD" / "Freedman-Diaconis" (with corresponding functions nclass.scott and nclass.FD). Case is ignored and partial matching is used. Alternatively, a function can be supplied which will compute the intended number of breaks or the actual breakpoints as a function of x."